# Tridion 2009 Website Translation Blueprinting

Tags: localization, translation, tridion

Within Tridion I am attempting to translate my English website into a German website. My approach is by utilizing the blueprinting heir-achy. The english content will be inhereted into a seperate folder that will be used to translate into german. In order to import my German xml files it requires me to localize the components in the German folder. Is there a way for me to localize  entire folders, structure groups, and even publication groups?

Answer (score 3):

I have to recommend against doing this on mass prior to importing the German items. It would be better to localize the items individually at time of import. This will mean you still get changes in inherited items like images and meta data. Always avoid localizing unless it is absolutely necessary.

Answer (score 2):

Although some parts of this question are a bit puzzling and probably (forgive me if I'm wrong) a sign of limited experience with Tridion, the question itself is quite clear: is it possible to localize entire folders or structure groups or even publications?
The answer is: yes, this is possible but only through the API. The GUI allows you to localize all items within a certain folder or structure group, but that will not localize items deeper in the folder / SG hierarchy. You would need to write some code that achieves this, probably through the Core Service (which is a WCF web service), or maybe with a GUI extension.

On a side note: when you do this, you need to decide what you want to achieve exactly. For example: which item types within a folder do you want to localize? My guess is components only, but maybe you want to localize (sub)folders and other types of items as well.

Answer (score 0):

When you localize an organizational item (e.g. folder) it localizes that item only.  I think you're asking whether it's possible to localize all the items contained within by localizing their parent organizational item.  I believe for this you'll need to resort to either:

1. A GUI extension where you can create your own "Localize Child Items" button.
2. An Event system where you can write an event handler which will fire when an organizational item is localized, which will, in turn, recursively localize any items within it.

Answer (score 0):

We have at least two quick options in the CME to do this.*

### Within an Organization Item

1. CTRL + A
2. Localize (right-click or use the button in the `Organize` tab) will then localize all first-level items in an Organizational Item

### Via Search

1. Do an Advanced Search
2. Check `Include Subfolders`
3. Optionally set  `Types` to `Components`
4. CTRL + A
5. Localize will then localize all selected items

You can also use CTRL+Click to un-select certain items.

**These work in at least SDL Tridion 2011, though I've seen CTRL+A and SHIFT-select work as far back as R5.3.*

As Nick describes, you probably don't want to localize the organizational items themselves. Do consider Quirijn's programmatic options and Chris's warning on reducing localization. See some advice on this on [SDLTridion for Strategists](http://tridionstrategist.blogspot.com/p/sdl-tridion-blueprint-minimizing.html).